# Spring Security 3.0.5 Session Expires Redirect

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to implement the  configuration but it never redirects me to my login.html page, any ideas?

Security Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="dc" />
    <global-method-security />
    <http access-denied-page="/auth/denied.html">
         <intercept-url filters="none" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" />
         <intercept-url filters="none" pattern="/services/rest-api/1.0/**" />
         <intercept-url filters="none" pattern="/preregistered/*"/>
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/**/*.xhtml"
            access="ROLE_NONE_GETS_ACCESS" />
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/auth/*"
            access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/preregistered/*"
            access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER"/>
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/registered/*"
            access="ROLE_USER"
            requires-channel="http"/>
        <form-login
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.html"
            login-page="/auth/login.html"
            default-target-url="/registered/home.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/auth/login.html" />
         <logout invalidate-session="true" 
              logout-url="/auth/logout.html" 
              success-handler-ref="DCLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
        <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="xmlAuthenticationFilter" />
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
    </http>
    <!-- Configure the authentication provider -->
    <authentication-manager alias="am">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager">
                <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
        <authentication-provider ref="xmlAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a lot of problems due to

```
filters="none"
```

try

```
access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"
```